# Api Validation Failed

Tags: node.js, api, postman, backend

When I try to validate the user it does not work.‘Validate register input’ does not helps me to validate the user. The payload and output from Postman are:
[image: 1]

Also, When I try

`console.log(req.body);`

inside the post request the output is:
[image: in the attached image]

Here is my complete code link : https://codesandbox.io/s/github/naima-shk/Twitter-Clone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code and it seems you have a logic error in your validation logic where you apply `isEmpty`:

```
 if(!Validator.isEmpty(data.handle)){
        errors.handle ="Handle field is required";
 }
 if(!Validator.isEmpty(data.email)){
       errors.email ="Email field is required";
 }
```

It should be the other way around (note that you have this error for other fields as well, so check those too):

```
 if(Validator.isEmpty(data.handle)){
        errors.handle ="Handle field is required";
 }
 if(Validator.isEmpty(data.email)){
       errors.email ="Email field is required";
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my mistake. But after correcting those mistakes it's still throwing the same error as before, sadly. :(

Comment: I've checked out the repo and fixed the validator mistakes and it works fine for me on my local machine - can you edit the question and add your updated code? Here's my version of your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-moore-fyzq5

Comment: Have you tried to run it by commenting on this line of code inside app.js ``` const newUser = new User({
        handle: 'nimi',
        email: 'nimi@nimi.nim',
        password: 'nim123'
      });
      user.save(); ```

Comment: Yes, I commented out all database related code to test the validation.

Comment: Any feedback? I can create a PR if it's still not working for you ..

Comment: Alright, But sadly I'm having the same error as before. it's not fixed yet. please create a pr and send me the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227957/discussion-between-eol-and-naima-shaikh).

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing correct value in email param, so of course it would throw validation error. Do it something like abc@gmail.com